# App is crashing for versions below 7.0(Nought)

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
at predictionguruji.in.fifapredictor.SplashScreen.onCreate
```

App is not opening in lower version devices.debug app is running correctly but downloaded app is not working in the same device.

Comment: Are you running the app using  Android studio?

Comment: yes Sir I am using Android studio for it.